# migrate SQL Database file from MYSQL 5.1.69 to 5.5.38-35.2

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress

I'm currently migrating a wordpress SQL database from IX Webhosting to Bluehost

When importing the SQL file, exported from MYSQL 5.1.69 into my bluehost MYSQL 5.5.38-35.2, the file says it imports successfully but is actually full of syntax errors:

For Example:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 6696: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1',  `lockout_username` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,  PRIMARY KEY (`lockout_id`),' at line 1
```

This is one of MANY.

I'm a novice at this stuff.

Could someone explain in the most layman terms possible, how to make an export from the 5.1.69 MYSQL DB that will be compatible with 5.5.38-35.2?

If I need to use a command line to make this export work, rather than php admin, could you explain where I would enter the command line.

Many thanks in advance. Spent hours trying to figure this out. Very confused right now.

Tom>>>>

Comment: Is it possible to post a few lines in error? Are the scripts generated by the phpmyadmin export feature?

Comment: There are tools at mysql.org to convert the data from one version to another.

Comment: Hi Jens. Do you know specifically which tool I need to use? A lot of stuff on the MYSQL website. Is it a free tool?

Comment: The errors occur when imported into MYSQL 5.5. Bluehost customer service told me the errors are all the same code: ERROR 1064